# Migrating problems when porting Django project to Python 3 and Django 2

Tags: python, django, django-2.0

I've been porting a Django project to Python 3 and Django 2. I have had to add on_delete to all my models with foreign keys as required in Django 2. Now I have tried to make migrations for those changes have been getting `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'`.

The file it references is the 0002 migration file not the models file which has been updated. I am not sure how to go about fixing this. I have tried faking the migrations and I still get the same error.

I am not sure why it thinks the database doesn't exist, I have checked and everything is intact and working in Postgres. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, the `on_delete=` field on a `ForeignKey` and `OneToOneField` are now requires. You should fix the migration files.

Comment: Isn't that the point of making migrations so that they are added to the migrations? If I add them to previously ran migrations files such as 0002, how would that work?

Comment: but you say you upgraded the Django version. So now you let a Django-2.0 framework interpret code written by a Django-1.x framework. Django is not 100% backwards compatible. The exceptions are listed in the release notes. In the previous versions of Django, these were not required.

Comment: I did upgrade versions and I also added the necessary field to the my models.py. Correct me if I am wrong but from what I understand 1) it should ignore 0002 file since it has already been ran and 2) when I update the models.py file make migrations should make the corresponding changes so they are documented for others to use.

Comment: no the migration files are each time interpreted. Since the migration file calls the `ForeignKey` constructor it will error. The fact that you already applied them is irrelevant. Since Django will interpret these to make a *directed acyclic graph* that it will topologically sort to run migrations it might not have run yet.

Comment: the release notes even specify that you should update the migration files. They advice to squash the files, such that you can more easily perform a search-and-replace.

Comment: Your correct, thanks for the info. The actual informational part is in the release notes for 1.9 and not 2.0 you may want to add that to your answer.

Comment: If I recall correctly it was marked "deprecated" since 1.9. But usually in Django something is deprecated for two released until it is actually removed, to give developers some time to adapt :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0) [**`ForeignKey`** fields [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) and [**`OneToOneField`** fields fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField) now have a required [**`on_delete`** parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete).

This is specified in the [release notes of Django-2.0 under *Features removed in 2.0*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.0/#features-removed-in-2-0):

> The **`on_delete` argument** for `ForeignKey` and `OneToOneField` is **now required** in models and migrations. Consider squashing **migrations** so that you have fewer of them **to update**.

You thus should inspect your migration files for `ForeignKey`s and `OneToOneField`s, and add an `on_delete` parameter, like:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = False

    dependencies = [
        ('app', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Model',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('some_foreignkey', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='app.OtherModel')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

You should inspect the [documentation on the `on_delete` parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) to see what deletion strategy is the best for each situation. The options are, at the time of writing `CASCADE`, `PROTECT`, `SET_NULL`, `SET_DEFAULT`, `SET(..)`, `DO_NOTHING`.

If you did not specify the `on_delete` in the pre-[django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0) versions, it made a default to `CASCADE`. So if you want the same behavior, you should add `on_delete=models.CASCADE`. This is noted in the [1.11 version of the documentation on `on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete):

> Deprecated since version 1.9: on_delete will become a required argument in Django 2.0. In **older versions it defaults to `CASCADE`**.

Comment: I had no luck with `django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE` (django-2.2.9), but plain `models.CASCADE` worked fine. This also seems to be what is suggested at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/1.9/#foreignkey-and-onetoonefield-on-delete-argument